# How to use images in the resources folder in a re-frame, re-agent app?

Tags: html, clojure, clojurescript

I have an app created using Chestnut, and there's an image in the project in the location: resources/public/img.png.
I want to use this image in my app, but doing `[:img {:src "public/img.png"}]` or `[:img {:src "./img.png"}]` doesn't work. What's the correct `src` for the image in the resources folder?

Answer (score 2):

The directory part `resources/public` is implicit. You need to access the file like:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

  ; something like this
  (slurp       (io/resource "img.png")) ; returns bytes from file
  (io/stream   (io/resource "img.png")) ; returns in InputStream for file
```

for example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(dotest
  (let [bytes (slurp (io/resource "sample.json"))]
    (spyx (count bytes))))
```

with result

```
(count bytes) => 72
```

Comment: Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Okay, so one thing I've noticed. When I go to localhost:3449, i.e., the Figwheel port, the src's work, but they don't on localhost:5000, where the app is running. What might be causing this?

Comment: The figwheel server automatically includes everything under `resources/public` on the classpath, so `io/resource` can find it.  If you have a 2nd server running on port 5000, you need to copy this behavior yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project.clj file and search for figwheel settings. Make sure that :http-server-root is uncommented.

```
:figwheel {
             :http-server-root "public"       ;; serve static assets from resources/public/

...

}
```

Then `[:img {:src "img.png" }]` should work.  And don't forget to restart figwheel.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm still unable to display images in the resources folder in my application using src.

Comment: Did you restart the server ?I had the same issue and doing this + restarting worked. Which version of chestnut are you using ?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server. It didn't work. Using Chestnut 0.18.0.

Comment: Okay, so one thing I've noticed. When I go to localhost:3449, i.e., the Figwheel port, the src's work, but they don't on localhost:5000, where the app is running. What might be causing this?

Comment: That's weird, cause I just did lein new chestnut demo-app, copied bunny.jpeg to resources/public folder and added   [:img {:src "bunny.jpg"}]]) in core.clj greeting function. And it worked. How are you running the app, do you run it via user namespace in repl  via (go) and (stop) ?

Comment: Ok, (stop) the server now and try ```lein cljsbuild once && lein run ```  inside project root dir.

Comment: If that works, then maybe you tampered with dev-system in user.clj, the wrap-file middleware needs to be there.

Comment: No lein cljsbuild once && lein run doesn't work either.

Comment: I also created a new chestnut project, copied an image into the public folder and then added [:img {:src "myimage.jpg"}] right under the chestnut "Helllo Chestnut!" greeting. Still no image.

Comment: Might be an issue with wrap-file indeed. I tried adding [wrap-file (fn [] "not found") "./"], in the config function, but on (go), I get, Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at ring.middleware.file/ensure-dir (file.clj:15).
No implementation of method: :as-file of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/Coercions found for class: vendo.config$config$fn__21654

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Chestnut. I'm assuming there is a webserver running, whose root dir is resources/public. I'm presuming there is a index.html (or equivalent) in that folder. I further assume that the Hiccup you want is in that index.html file. Given all of the above, I'd try

[:img {:src "img.png"}]

Comment: Yes, index.html and img.png are in the same directory resources/public and I have tried "img.png", but it doesn't work

Comment: And yes I want the hiccup in index.html

Comment: Does **anything** in the index.html show up? Something simple like a Hello World? If not, then perhaps what blushrt says below might be the issue.

Comment: Hello world does show up, but then <img src="img.png"> in index.html doesn't show up.

Comment: Okay, so one thing I've noticed. When I go to localhost:3449, i.e., the Figwheel port, the src's work, but they don't on localhost:5000, where the app is running. What might be causing this?